# Android AVD Manager Clone Device not working

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio / AVD Manager to create new device but when I select the 'clone device' button it goes blue but doesn't do anything..

Any tips?

I'm using studio 2.1 April 22 2016 release if that helps

Cheers!

Comment: Add your System your device which you are using etc

Comment: I'm on a Windows 10 64 machine machine Vaio SVF15A.

Comment: Also found the error..exception in Android Support

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a problem in the Android Studio version . Try to install the latest one .

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html